# How to remove all items in App Engine memcache in a particular namespace?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, memcached

I have a `java` project deployed in Google App engine and I use  `memcache` to temporarily store some info.

I have 2 environments, `live` & `testing`, so I use a different `memcache` namespace for each environment.

My problem is, if I applied this code:

```
MemcacheService memCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("TEST");
memCache.clearAll();
```

I thought it would only clear the items in that particular namespace `TEST`, but sadly based on [google memcache docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService) it turns out that it clears all items across all namespaces.

Is there any way to only clear all items in `memcache` in a particular namespace?